# Javascript: How to append user input from a text box to an array

Tags: javascript, function, dictionary

I'm building an app; the basic function is to populate a list with objects based on the key value. Then for that to populate a blank textbox... That works all good. What I want to do though... is use that same text box for the purpose of adding/removing user input to the function. So it can be stored and accessed. I need to a nudge in the right direction. Is it worth storing in a separate data array in a function... I've been looking online for help. And I'm torn between using json, saving in a dictionary.

Below will give you an idea of the mechanics in my script.

```
<script>
function populate(s1,s2){
var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
s2.innerHTML = "";
if(s1.value == "FMIP"){
          var optionArray = ["|","FMIP Object 1|FMIP"];
for(var option in optionArray){
    var chris = optionArray[option].split("|");
    var chris2 = document.createElement("option");
    chris2.value = chris[0];
    chris2.innerHTML = chris[1];
    s2.options.add(chris2);
    }
}
</script>


<select id="slct1" name="slct1" class="tbox4" 
onchange="populate(this.id,'slct2')">                                           
<option value=""></option>
<option value="FMIP">FMIP</option>

<select id="slct2" name="slct2" class="tbox3" 
onchange="document.form.ShowValue2.value=this.value">

 <!--- In this box below i would like to INPUT data... and for it to be 
 submitted and saved into my script (populate) function. So it is 
 callable from 'slct1' list. I also plan to be able to delete the data
 I know I'm probably going to have to restructure the code. And add a few 
 buttons for 'onclick' commands --->


<textarea name="ShowValue2" cols="40" rows="5" class="tbox"></textarea>
```

I'm obviously novice, so bare with with me. But all i need is a nudge in the right direction. Thank you kindly

Comment: Select your textarea and save its `value` to your storage on button click.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Am i able to save the input into a fucntion in this formation "object|object"